# Not able to redirect to quotes.php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, href

I have three pages index.php,author.php and quotes.php
In index.php I have given reference of author.php and in author.php I have given reference of quotes.php. 
I am able to redirect to author.php but not able to redirect to quotes.php here is my code of all three files.
Even though the reference given to quotes.php.both the time file is redirecting to author.php. 
help will be appreciated.

```
 index.php

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <title>Quotes</title>
 <head>
 <style>
 .dec {
 text-align:center;
 background-color: #000;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#383838,#080808);
 border: 1px solid #000;
 min-height: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 padding-top: 12px;
 }
 .dec a{
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 }
  a:hover{
  color:grey;
  text-decoration:underline;
 }
table a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none;}
table a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="dec">
<?php
 $chars = range('a', 'z');
 foreach($chars as $eachChar){
 echo '<a      href="http://localhost/quotes/authors/'.$eachChar.'.html">'.strtoupper($eachChar ).'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <?php include_once('dbconnect.php'); ?>
 <?php 

  $GetChR=isset($_REQUEST['authchar'])?$_REQUEST['authchar']:'a';
  $query= "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `col2` like      '".$GetChR."%'";//.$GetChR."%'";
 $dd = mysqli_query($con,$query);


  if($dd === FALSE) { 
  die(mysqli_error($con)); // TODO: better error handling
   }
  $output='';
  $count=1;
  $NothingFound=true;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dd))
  {
  $NothingFound=false;
  $output .='<tr><td style="width:3%;">'.$count.'.</td><td style="width:97%;">';
   $output .='<a  href="http://localhost/quotes/authors/'.$GetChR.'/'.$row['friendly_url'].'.html" >';
  $output .=$row['col2'].'</a></td></tr>';//here I  have given link so that author.php should redirect and it is working fine than what  is the  mistake in below link why it is not redirecting to quotes.php
  $count++;
    } 
    if($NothingFound){
    $output .='<tr><td>Nothing Found.</td></tr>';
     }
     ?>
      <table border="5" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-      collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#808080" width="100&#37;" id="AutoNumber2"   bgcolor="white">
       <tr><td width=100 colspan="2"><strong>Author Name</strong></td></tr>
       <?php echo  $output; ?>
       </table>
       </body>
       </html>
```

author.php

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <title>Quotes</title>
     <head>
     <style>
     .dec {
      text-align:center;
      background-color: #000;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#383838,#080808);
      border: 1px solid #000;
      min-height: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      padding-top: 12px;
       }
      .dec a{
       color:white;
       text-decoration:none;
        }
        a:hover{
        color:grey;
        text-decoration:underline;
        }
        table a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none;}
        table a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class ="dec">
        <?php
        $chars = range('a', 'z');
        foreach($chars as $eachChar){
        echo '<a   href="http://localhost/quotes/authors/'.$eachChar.'.html">'.strtoupper($eachChar              ).'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
          }
          ?>
          </div>
          <?php include_once('dbconnect.php'); ?>
          <?php 
            $authorname=isset($_REQUEST['authorname'])?      $_REQUEST['authorname']:'';
             $query= "SELECT table2.col2 AS a,table1.col2 AS b, table1.col1    AS c, table1.q_url AS d FROM table2, table1 WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col4 AND    table2.friendly_url= '".$authorname."'";
             $dd = mysqli_query($con,$query);
             if($dd === FALSE) { 
             die(mysqli_error($con)); // TODO: better error handling
              }
              $output='';
              $Authorname='';
              $count=1;
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dd))
              {
               $Authorname =$row['a'];
               $output .='<tr><td style="width:3%;">'.$count.'.</td><td   style="width:97%;">';
               $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
               $url=explode('/',$url);
               $output .='<a     href="http://localhost/quotes/authors/'.$url[5].'/'.$row['d'].'.html">';
               $output .=$row['b'].'</a></td></tr>';//here I  have given so that qoutes.php should redirect but it is not. is there any  mistake
               $count++;
               }
               ?>
               <table border="5" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"   style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#808080" width="100&#37;"  id="AutoNumber2" bgcolor="white">
              <tr><td width=100 colspan="2"><strong><?php echo $Authorname;   ?> Quotes</strong></td></tr>
              <?php echo  $output;?>
              </table>
              </body>
              </html>
```

quotes.php

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <title>Quotes</title>
       <head>
       <style>
       .dec {
        text-align:center;
        background-color: #000;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#383838,#080808);
        border: 1px solid #000;
        min-height: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
        padding-top: 12px;
         }
        .dec a{
         color:white;
         text-decoration:none;
          }
         a:hover{
         color:grey;
         text-decoration:underline;
         }
         table a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none;}
         table a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
         </style>
         </head>
         <body>
         <div class ="dec">
         <?php
         $chars = range('a', 'z');
         foreach($chars as $eachChar){
         echo '<a   href="http://localhost/quotes/'.$eachChar.'.html">'.strtoupper($eachChar).'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
         }
         ?>
         </div>
         <?php include_once('dbconnect.php'); ?>
         <?php 
         $qname=isset($_REQUEST['qname'])?$_REQUEST['qname']:'';
         $query= "SELECT col2 FROM  table1 WHERE q_url ='".$qname."'";
         $dd = mysqli_query($con,$query);
         if($dd === FALSE) { 
         die(mysqli_error($con)); // TODO: better error handling
         }
         $output='';
         $Authorname='';
         $count=1;
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dd))
         { 
          $output .='<tr><td style="width:3%;">'.$count.'.</td><td  style="width:97%;"><p>'.$row['col2'].'</p></td></tr>';
          $count++;
          }
          ?>
          <table border="5" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-  collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#808080" width="100&#37;" id="AutoNumber3"   bgcolor="white">
          <tr><td width=100 colspan="2"><strong><?php echo $Authorname; ?>   Quotes</strong></td></tr>
          <?php echo  $output; ?>
          </table>
          </body>
          </html>
```

.htaccess

```
      AddDefaultCharset utf-8
      Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
      RewriteEngine on 
      RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/index.php?authchar=$1 [L]
      RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/author.php?  authchar=$1&authorname=$2 [L]
      RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/quotes.php?  authchar=$1&authorname=$2&qname=$3 [L]
```

Comment: you know `[L]` means last? If you did you would understand that the last line of that htaccess file will likely never run.

Comment: I tried removing [L] but nothing happens

Comment: Aside: @ArtisiticPhoenix It's not just the `L` flag that prevents the following rule from working. Even without the `L` flag, the URL has already been rewritten, so the following rule would never match anyway. (Although there are other issues with the directives that would prevent it from rewriting correctly.)

Comment: @w3d - I figured that, I hate htaccess, it's like Regx but harder.

Comment: @w3d please tell me what you have figure out...

Comment: guys I came to know that it is redirecting to author.php. and not quotes.php... please look at my code and please help me out of the problem

Answer (score 3):

Aside from mispelling `qoutes.php`, your main problem is that you have 2 identical regular expressions that map to 2 different targets. So what happens is the first rule always gets the match, and the second rule will never do anything, ever. You need to do something to make the regex patterns different, like it looks like you're maybe trying to do this:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/index.php?authchar=$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/author.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/quotes.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2&qname=$3 [L]
```

Comment: > because of `[L]` or maybe not anyway but thought I would mention it.

Comment: @AlpeshPanchal - I think if you read the answer more careful you will see that another url segment was added in the above answer... ie 3 `/([^/]*)` instead of 2.